# Optimising Sort/deduplicate multi-elements in column data with EmEditor

Tags: performance, emeditor

When working with large delimited files, currently the easiest way to sort/deduplicate elements in a column (typically with elements separated with semicolon, but can be any char) seems to be via the
"Split column method" `document.SplitColumn` , and then bring back together using the Combine Lines method `document.CombineLines` (sorting/deduplicating as required, using the relevant method parameters).

This works ok when files aren't very big, but I was wondering if there is a faster/more optimal way of carrying out this common task on larger delimited files (million+ line), particularly via macro/method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update EmEditor to v20.1.901 or later, and use this form:

```
document.SplitColumn("3",";",eeSplitIntoNone,"A+",eeRemoveDuplicates | eeSortIgnorePrefix | eeSortStable,0);
```

This new `eeSplitIntoNone` type will not actually split, but only sort or remove duplicates of elements.

Comment: Great - I'll give it a try. Thanks.